# Stop tracking campaign

Tags: google-analytics

good afternoon

I am currently using google analytics to track the newsletters. For this I use campaigns.
The problem is that when you have finished visiting the linked page, the following pages continues indicating that this correspond to the same campaign.
How I can tell Google Analytics that the campaign tracking is finished?

I tried with the following code, but I ignored.

```
_gaq.push(
   ['_setCampaignTrack', false]
   ,['_setCampaignCookieTimeout', 0]
);

_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
```

Comment: This is how GA works. a traffic source is assigned to the whole visit, not only the first page in the visit. What do you think should be the traffic source for the subsequent pageviews? What was the outcome you were expecting?

Comment: Ok. But when i logout from web and close browser and reopen the page. The source is the same: Campaign. And i think that the source is direct, correct? This is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is intended behaviour for Google Analytics

> **Source precedence**—A direct traffic visit that follows a paid referred visit will never override an existing paid campaign. Whatever
>   is the latest paid campaign visit is listed as the referral for the
>   visit.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCampaigns?hl=en

direct traffic has a vey low precedence. Google Analytics assumes that if the visitor is coming back by a direct source it's probably because of the last visit that you actually paid for, so it keeps the last useful traffic source.

Comment: But my campaign is organic, it's a newsletter, right? How I can configure the campaign as organic?

Comment: A newsletter use campaign parameters. So it's considered a paid campaign.